# How to make a vote button count 1 vote per device/browser?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I made a vote button [**Here**](https://fiddle.jshell.net/tnvv0dds/7/) but the only problem is I am facing is, a user can cast votes unlimited times. I have no idea, how to limit 1 vote per device/browser. Can someone help me?

Comment: [What about adding a simple boolean in this fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/tnvv0dds/13/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to use cookies or local storage.

```
function checkIfUserVoted() {
    return true ? localStorage.getItem("userVoted") === "true" : false
}
```

This way you can just run the function before updating the counter to check if the user already voted. This will limit the voting to once per browser
[jsfiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/jmeng/g6Lhurae/)

Comment: Btw can't i stop them without creating a alert?

Comment: you can, but just for the example, I thought that an alert would be easiest. You can change the html of the button to Upvoted or Downvoted it you want. It doesn't matter